# Yarn 2 and dart sass with create react app

Tags: yarnpkg, sass-loader

I've been trying to update a Create React App to use yarn 2 and plug and play (PNP). When I do use `nodeLinker: node-modules` in the `.yarnrc.yml`, I can successfully start the dev-server. Without it, I end up with

```
./src/App.scss (./.yarn/$$virtual/css-loader-virtual-fe3fa7be11/0/cache/css-loader-npm-3.4.2-300ee159b3-2.zip/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./.yarn/cache/postcss-loader-npm-3.0.0-f4ab99b685-2.zip/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./.yarn/cache/resolve-url-loader-npm-3.1.1-cf1a268137-2.zip/node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./.yarn/unplugged/sass-loader-virtual-14ae4e1150/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/App.scss)
Error: A package is trying to access a peer dependency that should be provided by its direct ancestor but isn't

Required package: node-sass (via "node-sass")
Required by: sass-loader@virtual:74ba539c0b6c6c8346ea151c91664bff0bef13782983a6f90ddf1a26160140360771dcf40d0863b46ff7add674bc2c42a37daea25f24f4ea96f7843786460ecd#npm:8.0.2 (via /Users/me/color-contrast-matrix/.yarn/unplugged/sass-loader-virtual-14ae4e1150/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like yarn 2 provides a way of overriding a packages dependencies. You have to provide the missing dependency, at least in this case.

From the docs [current link](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#packageExtensions):

> Some packages may have been specified incorrectly with regard to their
>   dependencies - for example with one dependency being missing, causing
>   Yarn to refuse it the access. The packageExtensions fields offer a way
>   to extend the existing package definitions with additional
>   information. If you use it, consider sending a PR upstream and
>   contributing your extension to the plugin-compat database.

After installing `node-sass` and adding this config, compilation succeeded.

```
# .yarnrc.yml
packageExtensions:
  'sass-loader@*':
    optionalDependencies:
      node-sass: '*'
```

Comment: Cool. I have been looking for the answer for about a hour now. It resoled my problem. It works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work with yarn 2.4.0. `Usage Error: Unrecognized configuration settings found: packageExtensions['sass-loader@*'].optionalDependencies`

Comment: @RayShan take a look at https://github.com/wegry/yarn-2.4.0-package-extensions/pull/1/files for a more fleshed out example.

Comment: @wegry thanks, using `dependencies` instead of `optionalDependencies` worked for me too.

Answer (score 4):

Building on wegry's answer, a better way would be to fix up react-scripts, since that's where the missing peer dependency is.

```
#.yarnrc.yml

packageExtensions:
  'react-scripts@*':
    peerDependencies:
      node-sass: ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0'    # Or sass: ^1.3.0'
```

I'm using versions that match the peerDependency of the version of `sass-loader` that is currently depended on by `react-scripts`. (I hope by the time the next version of `react-scripts` comes out, they'll have fixed this bug.)

What this is doing, is telling Yarn that `react-scripts` really should have peer-depended on `sass` (and also `node-sass` for that matter), so that `sass-loader` can use them.

`sass-loader` itself has defined its dependencies correctly.

Comment: This is correct, the root cause is `react-scripts` not declaring them as peer dependencies. `sass-loader` is fine.